# Problemas com JavaScript função HTML não mostrar conteúdo no código fonte da página

Tags: javascript, append, código-fonte

Sobre as funções do JavaScript que adicionam conteúdo HTML, esses conteúdos adicionados não estão sendo mostrados no código fonte da página, mesmo funcionando.

Exemplo:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" 
     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
         </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>

<script>
    $("body").append("<p>Apareço no carregamento normal, mas não no código fonte </p>");
</script>

</html>
```

Possuo um plugin do jQuery de tabela, porém ele não consegue selecionar a tabela pois ela não tem as colunas ainda e já como crio as colunas dinamicamente, acabo não conseguindo usar o plugin.

--EDIT--
O meu problema estava na função assíncrona do ajax. Eu tinha uma função para ativar o plugin, e antes dela a função com ajax, já como a função do ajax ainda não retornava um valor, eu não conseguia ativar o plugim pois o objeto ainda não exisitia.
A solução foi colocar a ativação do plugin no success do ajax

Comment: Alterações feitas pelo JS só ficarão presentes no DOM, pois é o navegador que trata isso. O código fonte será sempre aquele que o navegador recebeu da requisição HTTP. Se precisa que algo esteja no código fonte, precisa colocá-lo lá explicitamente. Se quer algo dinâmico pode tentar utilizar uma linguagem no lado do servidor.

Comment: É possível pegar conteúdos adicionados dinamicamente ao DOM. Mas vc precisa mostrar como isso é feito.

Comment: Você poderia informar qual o plugin que está utilizando ?

Comment: Melhor seria você colocar o exemplo da sua real dúvida, com a tabela e o plugin, que ai torna-se facil a comunidade ajudar

Answer (score 0):

Para que o input type date receba o valor, você precisa enviar no formado `yyyy-MM-dd`, veja o snippet

```js
function adicionar() {
    const tabela = $('#tabela');
     
    const ParcelaVencimento = $('#ParcelaVencimento').val();
    // Converti para numeros
    const ParcelaValor = $('#ParcelaValor').val();

    // Usei o sinal de + para transformar em numero
    const QtdParcela = +$('#QtdParcela').val();

    // Iniciei um novo array para armazenar os subtotatis
    const subtotal = [];

    let total = 0;
    let vencimento = new Date();
    vencimento.setDate( ParcelaVencimento )
    // Aqui voce criou o contador como sendo $i ao invés de count    
    for ( let cont = 0; cont < QtdParcela; cont++ ) {

        subtotal.push( ParcelaValor * 1 );
        total += subtotal[ cont ];
        vencimento.setMonth( vencimento.getMonth() + 1 )

        // Dica: utilize templateString para facilitar a criacao do HTML
        var linha = `<tr class='selected' id='linha${cont}'>    
                            <td> <button type='button' class='btn btn-warning' onclick='apagar('${cont}');'> X </button></td>
                            <td> <input type='hidden' name='cont[]' value='${cont}'>'${cont +1}'</td>
                            <td> <input name='ParcelaVencimento[]'  type='date' value='${formatDate(vencimento)}'></td>
                            <td> <input type='number' name='ParcelaValor[]' value='${ParcelaValor}'></td>
                            <td> <input type='number' name='QtdParcela[]' value='${QtdParcela}'></td> 
                        </tr>`
        tabela.append( linha );
    }
  
}

// Função para formatar a data
function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Parcela vencimento: <input type="text" value="12" id="ParcelaVencimento"><br />
Parcela Valor: <input type="text" value ="123.30" id="ParcelaValor"><br />
Quantidade Parcelas: <input type="text" value="12" id="QtdParcela"><br />

<button onclick="adicionar()"> Gerar tabela </button> <br />

<table id="tabela"></table>
```